# Adjusted cox regression graph

Tags: r

I would like to make an adjusted cox regression analysis survival curve like this one but adjusted for  baseline measurements of `sex`, `age`, `trop`, `egfr`, `dm`, and `smoke`. The graph must be stratified according quartile of `delta_mon3_baseline_to_m1`.

[image]

Here are the code to get this univariate curve:

```
quantile <- df$delta_mon3_baseline_to_m1
```

```
fit <- survfit(Surv(mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, mace) ~ findInterval(quantile, quantile(quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5]), data = df)
```

```
custom_theme <- function(){
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.9)
    )
}
```

```
ggsurvplot(fit,
           pval = FALSE,
           ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
           censor = FALSE,
           legend = c(0.5, 0.2),
           legend.title = "Mon3, P=0.02",
           legend.labs = c("Quartile 1", "Quartile 2", "Quartile 3", "Quartile 4"),
           xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
           font.x = c(size = 15),
           ylab = "Survival from MACE",
           font.y = c(size = 15),
           break.y.by = 0.2,
           axes.offset = FALSE,
           palette = c("blue", "dark red", "green", "orange"))
```

Here are my data:

```
       ID age     sex  mace mace_months_date_vs_date_sample  trop egfr dm smoke   delta_mon3_baseline_to_m1
  1   121 NA        1     0                              43 21876 87    0     0                       -83.2  
  2    13 53        1     0                              69 1970  87    1     1                       -60.4  
  3   192 59        1     0                              44 871   90    1     0                       -52.2  
  4   120 71        1     1                               5 7860  58    1     0                       -46.1  
  5    54 59        1     0                              71 1500  81    1     1                       -45.0  
  6    68 58        1     0                              62 NA    90    0     1                       -36.2  
  7    41 57        0     0                              73 320   79    0     1                       -34.0  
  8    23 54        1     0                              72 8450  55    0     1                       -33.5  
  9    16 57        1     0                              73 180   99    0     1                       -30.6  
 10    45 51        0     0                              73 3710  65    0     1                       -28.5  
 11   216 69        1     0                              47 1730  51    0     1                       -27.1  
 12    61 48        1     0                              76 4470  90    0     1                       -26.4  
 13    24 47        1     0                              77 2390  90    0     1                       -25.5  
 14   136 49        1     0                              61 262   90    0     1                       -25.3  
 15    14 74        1     1                               6 7120  78    0     0                       -20.5  
 16    88 65        1     0                              47 16720 58    1     0                       -15.7  
 17    87 48        1     0                              46 1247  90    0     1                       -13.8  
 18    33 59        1     0                              69 2260  79    0     1                       -13.4  
 19   182 35        1     0                              44 NA    56    0     1                        -8.97 
 20    93 44        1     0                              43 NA    62    0     1                        -8.61 
 21   154 65        1     0                              46 54592 86    0     0                        -7.73 
 22    94 56        1     0                              45 1241  61    0     1                        -6.43 
 23   116 66        0     1                              16 2413  84    1     1                        -5.33 
 24   145 41        0     0                              62 NA    63    0     0                        -5.03 
 25    44 52        1     1                              30 2600  56    1     0                        -4.53 
 26   228 55        1     1                               8 45649 63    0     0                        -3.49 
 27    76 52        1     0                              48 NA    90    0     0                         0.407
 28    63 67        1     1                              15 NA    90    0     0                         2.77 
 29    59 61        1     0                              79 160   85    0     1                         3.37 
 30    42 38        1     0                              69 1800  69    0     1                         4.49 
 31   219 65        1     0                              62 843   64    0     0                         7.30 
 32    47 62        1     0                              69 1420  85    0     0                         8.13 
 33    56 43        1     0                              70 1360  90    1     0                         9.43 
 34   175 61        0     0                              46 NA    67    1     1                        10.6  
 35   164 75        0     0                              62 1470  45    0     1                        11.1  
 36   181 56        1     0                              45 372   90    0     0                        12.7  
 37   234 37        1     0                              55 844   78    0     0                        13.0  
 38   146 75        1     1                              21 1454  65    1     1                        14.5  
 39    28 76        1     0                              71 40    90    1     1                        15.4  
 40   242 68        0     1                              41 50000 69    0     1                        15.5  
 41    52 49        1     0                              74 1740  71    0     1                        19.3  
 42    71 59        1     0                              45 11450 90    0     0                        19.4  
 43    67 52        1     0                              46 769   90    0     1                        19.7  
 44   187 59        1     0                              45 2234  59    0     0                        21.4  
 45   128 59        1     0                              50 349   54    0     1                        22.0  
 46    27 28        1     0                              71 6440  90    0     1                        23.3  
 47   151 63        0     0                              62 250   60    0     1                        23.4  
 48   215 62        0     0                              43 3654  68    0     0                        26.5  
 49   132 57        1     1                               4 8421  86    0     0                        26.7  
 50    21 46        1     0                              75 3600  87    0     1                        27.4  
 51   173 48        1     1                               1 NA    42    0     1                        29.6  
 52   124 65        0     1                               4 5204  73    1     1                        29.7  
 53   119 41        1     0                              63 440   90    0     0                        31.9  
 54   224 60        1     1                              17 NA    85    0     0                        34.9  
 55    29 73        0     0                              77 NA    51    0     0                        39.5  
 56    49 54        1     1                              28 NA    76    1     0                        64.7  
 57   140 77        1     1                               3 40273 63    1     1                        66.8  
 58   221 66        1     0                              45 90    90    0     0                        70.4  
 59   172 50        1     1                               2 9352  86    0     1                        72.1  
 60   115 51        0     0                              50 2177  68    0     1                        73.0  
 61    12 57        1     0                              71 6020  88    0     1                        84.1  
 62   103 81        1     1                               1 10014 71    0     0                        95.7  
 63   223 63        1     0                              46 4281  90    0     0                        NA    
 64    32 66        1     0                              73 1710  90    1     0                        NA    
 65    50 54        1     0                              70 15300 90    0     1                        NA    
 66    57 58        1     0                              74 5010  68    0     1                        NA    
 67    20 56        1     1                               5 NA    75    0     1                        NA    
 68    17 44        1     0                              77 840   71    0     0                        NA    
 69    79 68        1     0                              45 776   90    0     0                        NA    
 70    35 47        1     0                              77 NA    83    0     0                        NA    
 71    22 46        1     0                              77 5330  88    0     1                        NA    
 72    26 66        1     0                              77 500   51    0     0                        NA    
 73    25 54        1     0                              73 1080  87    0     0                        NA    
 74    31 47        0     0                              72 6490  77    1     1                        NA    
 75    15 65        1     1                              43 6300  49    1     0                        NA    
 76    43 59        0     0                              74 2100  84    0     1                        NA    
 77    36 64        1     1                               5 15940 52    0     1                        NA    
 78    30 73        0     0                              68 3340  48    1     1                        NA    
 79    39 54        1     0                              74 990   77    0     0                        NA    
 80    60 72        1     0                              76 470   62    0     0                        NA    
 81    55 47        1     0                              70 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
 82    37 81        1     0                              74 NA    99    1     1                        NA    
 83    19 66        1     0                              78 9320  59    0     0                        NA    
 84   139 39        0     0                              58 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
 85    38 55        1     0                              78 3930  90    1     0                        NA    
 86    18 56        1     0                              69 6390  90    0     1                        NA    
 87    58 36        1     0                              76 NA    78    1     1                        NA    
 88    73 61        1     0                              44 11    90    0     0                        NA    
 89   194 64        1     1                              15 11135 68    0     1                        NA    
 90   106 48        1     0                              46 5256  63    0     1                        NA    
 91   193 63        1     0                              46 1753  81    0     0                        NA    
 92   148 78        1     1                               7 NA    76    1     1                        NA    
 93   156 79        1     1                               8 NA    61    1     0                        NA    
 94   203 51        0     0                              62 50    75    0     1                        NA    
 95   100 74        1     1                              16 8903  84    0     0                        NA    
 96    81 52        1     0                              47 3598  90    0     1                        NA    
 97   190 73        0     1                              19 2483  90    1     0                        NA    
 98   206 82        0     0                              61 NA    48    0     0                        NA    
 99   233 58        1     0                              46 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
100   189 72        0     1                               1 NA    77    0     1                        NA    
101   105 63        1     1                               4 1557  68    0     1                        NA    
102   220 67        1     0                              48 5247  90    0     1                        NA    
103    85 72        0     1                              61 24    64    0     1                        NA    
104    11 51        1     0                              43 2993  90    0     1                        NA    
105   205 68        1     0                              46 3624  90    1     1                        NA    
106   131 41        1     0                              61 751   61    0     1                        NA    
107     1 66        1     0                              44 NA    84    1     1                        NA    
108   225 69        1     0                              48 NA    80    1     1                        NA    
109   183 60        1     1                               1 24160 69    0     1                        NA    
110   213 66        1     1                               5 NA    58    0     0                        NA    
111     7 71        1     0                              43 NA    65    0     1                        NA    
112   147 45        1     0                              43 5687  86    1     1                        NA    
113   134 81        0     0                              46 1911  86    0     0                        NA    
114    86 52        1     0                              58 NA    46    0     1                        NA    
115    69 67        1     1                               3 NA    56    0     0                        NA    
116   212 58        1     0                              55 1855  90    0     0                        NA    
117   199 63        0     1                              27 9951  46    0     1                        NA    
118    75 47        1     1                               1 13374 87    0     0                        NA    
119   137 63        0     0                              47 2107  84    1     1                        NA    
120   191 67        1     1                              19 4927  68    0     0                        NA    
121   245 62        1     1                              11 83    67    0     1                        NA    
122   111 72        1     1                               1 2380  72    0     0                        NA    
123   153 75        0     1                               1 663   35    0     0                        NA    
124   112 46        1     1                               1 NA    86    0     1                        NA    
125    89 73        1     1                               2 NA    74    0     0                        NA    
126   243 57        1     0                              48 NA    78    1     1                        NA    
127   109 75        1     0                              62 NA    67    0     1                        NA    
128   165 68        0     0                              61 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
129    95 68        1     1                              23 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
130   231 73        1     1                               1 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
131     5 51        1     0                              55 1627  76    0     0                        NA    
132   168 59        1     1                              19 NA    90    1     1                        NA    
133   159 59        1     0                              48 1211  86    0     0                        NA    
134     6 60        1     1                               1 5654  63    0     1                        NA    
135   179 54        1     0                              43 NA    63    0     0                        NA    
136    77 62        1     0                              47 NA    53    0     0                        NA    
137   155 64        1     1                               1 10000 90    0     0                        NA    
138   171 48        1     0                              46 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
139   174 73        1     1                              11 NA    75    1     1                        NA    
140    84 79        1     0                              46 NA    64    0     0                        NA    
141   102 58        1     0                              48 2956  69    0     0                        NA    
142   207 46        0     0                              46 67927 68    0     1                        NA    
143   230 75        1     1                              32 NA    52    1     0                        NA    
144   138 63        0     0                              50 63    49    0     1                        NA    
145   188 68        1     0                              61 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
146   241 60        1     0                              62 4790  65    1     1                        NA    
147    72 54        1     0                              48 NA    86    0     1                        NA    
148   235 78        0     1                              46 NA    42    1     0                        NA    
149   211 54        1     0                              55 3569  63    0     1                        NA    
150   127 46        0     0                              62 961   90    0     1                        NA    
151   237 49        0     0                              55 6581  90    0     1                        NA    
152    70 67        1     0                              43 253   73    1     0                        NA    
153   210 79        0     0                              61 2888  75    0     0                        NA    
154   110 54        0     0                              47 33017 66    0     0                        NA    
155   133 47        1     0                              59 1675  64    0     0                        NA    
156     2 51        1     0                              50 438   90    0     1                        NA    
157   218 66        1     1                              10 15543 35    0     0                        NA    
158   180 61        1     0                              55 6212  90    0     1                        NA    
159   229 64        0     0                              63 6694  82    1     1                        NA    
160    65 79        0     0                              55 NA    90    1     1                        NA    
161   130 73        1     0                              48 1945  84    0     0                        NA    
162    96 51        0     1                              31 3004  61    0     1                        NA    
163   226 52        1     1                              32 3789  90    0     1                        NA    
164   152 52        1     0                              48 NA    86    0     0                        NA    
165   197 76        0     0                              55 2844  51    0     0                        NA    
166   178 75        0     0                              62 950   52    0     1                        NA    
167   141 56        1     0                              59 123   69    1     1                        NA    
168   195 76        1     1                              53 6630  54    1     0                        NA    
169    92 54        1     0                              48 3220  90    0     1                        NA    
170   162 82        0     0                              48 2040  75    1     0                        NA    
171   201 62        1     0                              62 NA    85    0     1                        NA    
172   217 57        0     0                              59 6672  72    0     1                        NA    
173   222 53        1     1                               4 1480  90    0     1                        NA    
174   208 42        1     1                               4 6979  80    0     1                        NA    
175   104 63        0     1                              25 NA    54    0     1                        NA    
176   160 37        1     0                              59 1411  58    0     1                        NA    
177    66 66        1     0                              48 5711  90    0     0                        NA    
178    74 46        1     0                              60 NA    89    0     1                        NA    
179   185 76        1     1                              43 2340  72    0     0                        NA    
180   177 39        1     0                              58 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
181   123 51        1     0                              49 57    84    0     1                        NA    
182   184 80        1     1                               1 NA    33    1     1                        NA    
183   204 69        1     1                               8 33    74    0     1                        NA    
184   227 76        1     1                               1 5110  36    1     1                        NA    
185   125 48        1     0                              63 NA    56    0     1                        NA    
186    83 65        1     0                              51 2797  61    0     0                        NA    
187     8 59        1     0                              55 1035  63    0     1                        NA    
188   143 76        1     0                              47 2840  77    0     1                        NA    
189     9 57        0     0                              49 251   84    0     1                        NA    
190     3 66        0     0                              55 7671  85    0     0                        NA    
191   117 69        0     0                              49 6155  90    0     1                        NA    
192    10 68        1     0                              55 4299  90    1     1                        NA    
193   198 72        1     1                              13 NA    51    1     0                        NA    
194   244 62        0     0                              60 846   90    0     1                        NA    
195   108 56        1     1                               2 2339  90    0     1                        NA    
196    34 51        1     1                              13 400   68    1     0                        NA    
197   214 60        1     1                               3 86115 90    0     1                        NA    
198     4 71        1     1                              25 27    52    0     0                        NA    
199    97 68        1     1                               7 87355 90    1     0                        NA    
200   200 77        1     0                              62 NA    48    1     0                        NA    
201   113 28        1     0                              62 8669  90    0     1                        NA    
202    80 62        1     0                              60 NA    82    0     0                        NA    
203   166 51        1     1                              10 NA    86    0     1                        NA    
204    98 61        1     0                              61 NA    67    0     0                        NA    
205   238 56        1     0                              45 1258  90    0     1                        NA    
206   239 72        1     1                               3 3000  76    1     1                        NA    
207   114 79        0     1                              11 NA    14    1     1                        NA    
208   167 62        1     0                              51 137   63    0     0                        NA    
209    64 68        0     0                              47 3866  59    1     1                        NA    
210   157 68        0     1                               1 NA    82    0     0                        NA    
211    90 49        1     0                              46 1312  90    0     0                        NA    
212   149 75        0     0                              63 NA    39    1     1                        NA    
213   129 64        1     0                              60 NA    77    0     1                        NA    
214   170 48        0     0                              43 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
215    91 51        1     0                              62 NA    78    2     1                        NA    
216   135 68        1     0                              58 NA    74    1     1                        NA    
217   122 68        1     0                              61 2103  54    0     1                        NA    
218   240 70        0     1                               1 1586  36    0     0                        NA    
219    99 73        1     1                               2 601   58    0     1                        NA    
220   236 54        1     1                              46 1472  69    0     1                        NA    
221   144 47        1     1                               1 1692  NA    0     1                        NA    
222    53 79        1     1                              13 NA    53    1     0                        NA    
223   176 40        0     0                              54 2102  90    0     1                        NA    
224   107 52        1     0                              48 6452  90    0     1                        NA    
225   232 58        1     0                              54 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
226   163 69        1     0                              45 NA    88    0     0                        NA    
227   142 61        1     0                              45 1244  90    0     0                        NA    
228   118 44        1     1                              31 2051  90    0     1                        NA    
229   126 57        1     0                              48 1007  90    0     0                        NA    
230   158 55        1     0                              42 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
231   186 43        1     0                              49 NA    90    0     1                        NA    
232    82 61        1     0                              43 NA    63    0     0                        NA    
233    78 44        1     0                              61 1726  87    0     0                        NA    
234    48 77        1     1                               1 3400  48    0     0                        NA    
235    62 35        1     1                              31 2143  90    0     0                        NA    
236   209 74        0     1                               1 NA    55    1     0                        NA    
237   196 72        0     0                              63 236   70    NA    NA                       NA    
238    46 60        1     1                              11 3930  65    1     0                        NA    
239   150 44        1     0                              47 31026 90    1     0                        NA    
240   161 53        1     1                              39 NA    NA    0     1                        NA    
241   169 61        1     1                               7 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
242   101 NA        1     0                              42 NA    90    0     0                        NA    
243   202 80        1     1                               1 NA    72    0     0                        NA    
244    51 73        0     1                               1 5280  66    0     0                        NA    
245    40 72        1     1                               1 1230  55    0     1                        NA
```

[image]

with this code:

```
df$quantile <- findInterval(quantile, quantile(quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5])

df$surv <- Surv(df$mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, df$mace)

mod <- coxph(surv ~ strata(quantile) + dm + age + sex + trop + egfr + smoke, 
             data = df)

ggsurvplot(survfit(mod, data = df),
           pval = FALSE,
           ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
           censor = FALSE,
           legend = c(0.5, 0.2),
           legend.title = "Mon3, P=0.02",
           legend.labs = c("Quartile 1", "Quartile 2", "Quartile 3", "Quartile 4"),
           xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
           font.x = c(size = 15),
           ylab = "Survival from MACE",
           font.y = c(size = 15),
           break.y.by = 0.2,
           axes.offset = FALSE,
           palette = c("blue", "dark red", "green", "orange"))
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi Max. This is the third time you have asked the same question. Please don't do that. The reason why you haven't had a satisfactory answer yet is that it isn't clear what you are asking. Do you want survival curves for this variable at the mean of the covariates?

Comment: Hi Allan, apologies. Yes an adjusted cox regression according the delta mon3 variable adjusted by mean of the baseline covariates. I thank you.

Comment: Is your actual data longer? You only have 5 non-NA values in each quantile, and a total of 4 events. You have more covariates than events, so the coxph model you want won't converge with the data you have supplied. Are you able to share your whole data set?

Comment: ```delta_mon3_baseline_to_m1```is the difference between baseline measurements and measurements after 1 month of Mon1. There are 248 baseline measurements but only 46 measures at 1 month. So yes, the data are longer but because the 1-month measurements are shorter, I only included the 46 baseline data. I hope it makes sense. However, covariables data are measures at baseline. Thanks.

Comment: but 26 of them are NA, so you only have 20 values left for the regression. There are nowhere near enough data points for the model you want to fit. - one of your quartiles doesn’t even have any events in it.

Comment: Are you able to share the data and code that produced the plot? That looks more promising.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question.

Comment: @AllanCameron any chance you've got idea here? Thanks

Comment: The problem, as I mentioned above is that the data you have provided doesn't produce the plot at the top of your question. There is data missing. As I have said, you cannot fit the model you want to the data you have given in your question (as in, there are simply not enough data points to support the model you want). Please share the full data set if you would like me to have a look at it - thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron. Thanks! I have updated the question and put the entire data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the full  data set, we can now plot the coxph model like this:

```r
df$quantile <- findInterval(quantile, quantile(quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5])
df$surv <- Surv(df$mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, df$mace)

mod <- coxph(surv ~ strata(quantile) + dm + age + sex + trop + egfr + smoke, 
             data = df)

ggsurvplot(survfit(mod, data = df),
          pval = FALSE,
          ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
          censor = FALSE,
          legend = c(0.5, 0.2),
          legend.title = "Mon3, P=0.02",
          legend.labs = c("Quartile 1", "Quartile 2", "Quartile 3", "Quartile 4"),
          xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
          font.x = c(size = 15),
          ylab = "Survival from MACE",
          font.y = c(size = 15),
          break.y.by = 0.2,
          axes.offset = FALSE,
          palette = c("blue", "dark red", "green", "orange"))
```

[image]

---

**FULLY REPRODUCIBLE SCRIPT**

```r
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(survminer)

df <- structure(list(ID = c(121L, 13L, 192L, 120L, 54L, 68L, 41L, 23L, 
16L, 45L, 216L, 61L, 24L, 136L, 14L, 88L, 87L, 33L, 182L, 93L, 
154L, 94L, 116L, 145L, 44L, 228L, 76L, 63L, 59L, 42L, 219L, 47L, 
56L, 175L, 164L, 181L, 234L, 146L, 28L, 242L, 52L, 71L, 67L, 
187L, 128L, 27L, 151L, 215L, 132L, 21L, 173L, 124L, 119L, 224L, 
29L, 49L, 140L, 221L, 172L, 115L, 12L, 103L, 223L, 32L, 50L, 
57L, 20L, 17L, 79L, 35L, 22L, 26L, 25L, 31L, 15L, 43L, 36L, 30L, 
39L, 60L, 55L, 37L, 19L, 139L, 38L, 18L, 58L, 73L, 194L, 106L, 
193L, 148L, 156L, 203L, 100L, 81L, 190L, 206L, 233L, 189L, 105L, 
220L, 85L, 11L, 205L, 131L, 1L, 225L, 183L, 213L, 7L, 147L, 134L, 
86L, 69L, 212L, 199L, 75L, 137L, 191L, 245L, 111L, 153L, 112L, 
89L, 243L, 109L, 165L, 95L, 231L, 5L, 168L, 159L, 6L, 179L, 77L, 
155L, 171L, 174L, 84L, 102L, 207L, 230L, 138L, 188L, 241L, 72L, 
235L, 211L, 127L, 237L, 70L, 210L, 110L, 133L, 2L, 218L, 180L, 
229L, 65L, 130L, 96L, 226L, 152L, 197L, 178L, 141L, 195L, 92L, 
162L, 201L, 217L, 222L, 208L, 104L, 160L, 66L, 74L, 185L, 177L, 
123L, 184L, 204L, 227L, 125L, 83L, 8L, 143L, 9L, 3L, 117L, 10L, 
198L, 244L, 108L, 34L, 214L, 4L, 97L, 200L, 113L, 80L, 166L, 
98L, 238L, 239L, 114L, 167L, 64L, 157L, 90L, 149L, 129L, 170L, 
91L, 135L, 122L, 240L, 99L, 236L, 144L, 53L, 176L, 107L, 232L, 
163L, 142L, 118L, 126L, 158L, 186L, 82L, 78L, 48L, 62L, 209L, 
196L, 46L, 150L, 161L, 169L, 101L, 202L, 51L, 40L), age = c(NA, 
53L, 59L, 71L, 59L, 58L, 57L, 54L, 57L, 51L, 69L, 48L, 47L, 49L, 
74L, 65L, 48L, 59L, 35L, 44L, 65L, 56L, 66L, 41L, 52L, 55L, 52L, 
67L, 61L, 38L, 65L, 62L, 43L, 61L, 75L, 56L, 37L, 75L, 76L, 68L, 
49L, 59L, 52L, 59L, 59L, 28L, 63L, 62L, 57L, 46L, 48L, 65L, 41L, 
60L, 73L, 54L, 77L, 66L, 50L, 51L, 57L, 81L, 63L, 66L, 54L, 58L, 
56L, 44L, 68L, 47L, 46L, 66L, 54L, 47L, 65L, 59L, 64L, 73L, 54L, 
72L, 47L, 81L, 66L, 39L, 55L, 56L, 36L, 61L, 64L, 48L, 63L, 78L, 
79L, 51L, 74L, 52L, 73L, 82L, 58L, 72L, 63L, 67L, 72L, 51L, 68L, 
41L, 66L, 69L, 60L, 66L, 71L, 45L, 81L, 52L, 67L, 58L, 63L, 47L, 
63L, 67L, 62L, 72L, 75L, 46L, 73L, 57L, 75L, 68L, 68L, 73L, 51L, 
59L, 59L, 60L, 54L, 62L, 64L, 48L, 73L, 79L, 58L, 46L, 75L, 63L, 
68L, 60L, 54L, 78L, 54L, 46L, 49L, 67L, 79L, 54L, 47L, 51L, 66L, 
61L, 64L, 79L, 73L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 76L, 75L, 56L, 76L, 54L, 82L, 
62L, 57L, 53L, 42L, 63L, 37L, 66L, 46L, 76L, 39L, 51L, 80L, 69L, 
76L, 48L, 65L, 59L, 76L, 57L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 72L, 62L, 56L, 51L, 
60L, 71L, 68L, 77L, 28L, 62L, 51L, 61L, 56L, 72L, 79L, 62L, 68L, 
68L, 49L, 75L, 64L, 48L, 51L, 68L, 68L, 70L, 73L, 54L, 47L, 79L, 
40L, 52L, 58L, 69L, 61L, 44L, 57L, 55L, 43L, 61L, 44L, 77L, 35L, 
74L, 72L, 60L, 44L, 53L, 61L, NA, 80L, 73L, 72L), sex = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), mace = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
mace_months_date_vs_date_sample = c(43L, 
69L, 44L, 5L, 71L, 62L, 73L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 47L, 76L, 77L, 61L, 
6L, 47L, 46L, 69L, 44L, 43L, 46L, 45L, 16L, 62L, 30L, 8L, 48L, 
15L, 79L, 69L, 62L, 69L, 70L, 46L, 62L, 45L, 55L, 21L, 71L, 41L, 
74L, 45L, 46L, 45L, 50L, 71L, 62L, 43L, 4L, 75L, 1L, 4L, 63L, 
17L, 77L, 28L, 3L, 45L, 2L, 50L, 71L, 1L, 46L, 73L, 70L, 74L, 
5L, 77L, 45L, 77L, 77L, 77L, 73L, 72L, 43L, 74L, 5L, 68L, 74L, 
76L, 70L, 74L, 78L, 58L, 78L, 69L, 76L, 44L, 15L, 46L, 46L, 7L, 
8L, 62L, 16L, 47L, 19L, 61L, 46L, 1L, 4L, 48L, 61L, 43L, 46L, 
61L, 44L, 48L, 1L, 5L, 43L, 43L, 46L, 58L, 3L, 55L, 27L, 1L, 
47L, 19L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 48L, 62L, 61L, 23L, 1L, 55L, 19L, 
48L, 1L, 43L, 47L, 1L, 46L, 11L, 46L, 48L, 46L, 32L, 50L, 61L, 
62L, 48L, 46L, 55L, 62L, 55L, 43L, 61L, 47L, 59L, 50L, 10L, 55L, 
63L, 55L, 48L, 31L, 32L, 48L, 55L, 62L, 59L, 53L, 48L, 48L, 62L, 
59L, 4L, 4L, 25L, 59L, 48L, 60L, 43L, 58L, 49L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 63L, 
51L, 55L, 47L, 49L, 55L, 49L, 55L, 13L, 60L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 25L, 
7L, 62L, 62L, 60L, 10L, 61L, 45L, 3L, 11L, 51L, 47L, 1L, 46L, 
63L, 60L, 43L, 62L, 58L, 61L, 1L, 2L, 46L, 1L, 13L, 54L, 48L, 
54L, 45L, 45L, 31L, 48L, 42L, 49L, 43L, 61L, 1L, 31L, 1L, 63L, 
11L, 47L, 39L, 7L, 42L, 1L, 1L, 1L), trop = c(21876L, 1970L, 
871L, 7860L, 1500L, NA, 320L, 8450L, 180L, 3710L, 1730L, 4470L, 
2390L, 262L, 7120L, 16720L, 1247L, 2260L, NA, NA, 54592L, 1241L, 
2413L, NA, 2600L, 45649L, NA, NA, 160L, 1800L, 843L, 1420L, 1360L, 
NA, 1470L, 372L, 844L, 1454L, 40L, 50000L, 1740L, 11450L, 769L, 
2234L, 349L, 6440L, 250L, 3654L, 8421L, 3600L, NA, 5204L, 440L, 
NA, NA, NA, 40273L, 90L, 9352L, 2177L, 6020L, 10014L, 4281L, 
1710L, 15300L, 5010L, NA, 840L, 776L, NA, 5330L, 500L, 1080L, 
6490L, 6300L, 2100L, 15940L, 3340L, 990L, 470L, NA, NA, 9320L, 
NA, 3930L, 6390L, NA, 11L, 11135L, 5256L, 1753L, NA, NA, 50L, 
8903L, 3598L, 2483L, NA, NA, NA, 1557L, 5247L, 24L, 2993L, 3624L, 
751L, NA, NA, 24160L, NA, NA, 5687L, 1911L, NA, NA, 1855L, 9951L, 
13374L, 2107L, 4927L, 83L, 2380L, 663L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1627L, NA, 1211L, 5654L, NA, NA, 10000L, NA, NA, NA, 2956L, 
67927L, NA, 63L, NA, 4790L, NA, NA, 3569L, 961L, 6581L, 253L, 
2888L, 33017L, 1675L, 438L, 15543L, 6212L, 6694L, NA, 1945L, 
3004L, 3789L, NA, 2844L, 950L, 123L, 6630L, 3220L, 2040L, NA, 
6672L, 1480L, 6979L, NA, 1411L, 5711L, NA, 2340L, NA, 57L, NA, 
33L, 5110L, NA, 2797L, 1035L, 2840L, 251L, 7671L, 6155L, 4299L, 
NA, 846L, 2339L, 400L, 86115L, 27L, 87355L, NA, 8669L, NA, NA, 
NA, 1258L, 3000L, NA, 137L, 3866L, NA, 1312L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 2103L, 1586L, 601L, 1472L, 1692L, NA, 2102L, 6452L, NA, NA, 
1244L, 2051L, 1007L, NA, NA, NA, 1726L, 3400L, 2143L, NA, 236L, 
3930L, 31026L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5280L, 1230L), egfr = c(87L, 87L, 
90L, 58L, 81L, 90L, 79L, 55L, 99L, 65L, 51L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 78L, 
58L, 90L, 79L, 56L, 62L, 86L, 61L, 84L, 63L, 56L, 63L, 90L, 90L, 
85L, 69L, 64L, 85L, 90L, 67L, 45L, 90L, 78L, 65L, 90L, 69L, 71L, 
90L, 90L, 59L, 54L, 90L, 60L, 68L, 86L, 87L, 42L, 73L, 90L, 85L, 
51L, 76L, 63L, 90L, 86L, 68L, 88L, 71L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 68L, 75L, 
71L, 90L, 83L, 88L, 51L, 87L, 77L, 49L, 84L, 52L, 48L, 77L, 62L, 
90L, 99L, 59L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 78L, 90L, 68L, 63L, 81L, 76L, 61L, 
75L, 84L, 90L, 90L, 48L, 90L, 77L, 68L, 90L, 64L, 90L, 90L, 61L, 
84L, 80L, 69L, 58L, 65L, 86L, 86L, 46L, 56L, 90L, 46L, 87L, 84L, 
68L, 67L, 72L, 35L, 86L, 74L, 78L, 67L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 76L, 90L, 
86L, 63L, 63L, 53L, 90L, 90L, 75L, 64L, 69L, 68L, 52L, 49L, 90L, 
65L, 86L, 42L, 63L, 90L, 90L, 73L, 75L, 66L, 64L, 90L, 35L, 90L, 
82L, 90L, 84L, 61L, 90L, 86L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 54L, 90L, 75L, 85L, 
72L, 90L, 80L, 54L, 58L, 90L, 89L, 72L, 90L, 84L, 33L, 74L, 36L, 
56L, 61L, 63L, 77L, 84L, 85L, 90L, 90L, 51L, 90L, 90L, 68L, 90L, 
52L, 90L, 48L, 90L, 82L, 86L, 67L, 90L, 76L, 14L, 63L, 59L, 82L, 
90L, 39L, 77L, 90L, 78L, 74L, 54L, 36L, 58L, 69L, NA, 53L, 90L, 
90L, 90L, 88L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 63L, 87L, 48L, 90L, 55L, 
70L, 65L, 90L, NA, 90L, 90L, 72L, 66L, 55L), dm = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), smoke = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), delta_mon3_baseline_to_m1 = c(-83.2, 
-60.4, -52.2, -46.1, -45, -36.2, -34, -33.5, -30.6, -28.5, -27.1, 
-26.4, -25.5, -25.3, -20.5, -15.7, -13.8, -13.4, -8.97, -8.61, 
-7.73, -6.43, -5.33, -5.03, -4.53, -3.49, 0.407, 2.77, 3.37, 
4.49, 7.3, 8.13, 9.43, 10.6, 11.1, 12.7, 13, 14.5, 15.4, 15.5, 
19.3, 19.4, 19.7, 21.4, 22, 23.3, 23.4, 26.5, 26.7, 27.4, 29.6, 
29.7, 31.9, 34.9, 39.5, 64.7, 66.8, 70.4, 72.1, 73, 84.1, 95.7, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", 
"218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", 
"227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245"))


quantile <- df$delta_mon3_baseline_to_m1
df$quantile <- findInterval(quantile, quantile(quantile, na.rm = TRUE)[-5])

df$surv <- Surv(df$mace_months_date_vs_date_sample, df$mace)

mod <- coxph(surv ~ strata(quantile) + dm + age + sex + trop + egfr + smoke, 
             data = df)

custom_theme <- function(){
  theme_survminer() %+replace%
    theme(
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "black"),
      plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.9)
    )
}

ggsurvplot(survfit(mod, data = df),
           pval = FALSE,
           ggtheme = custom_theme(), 
           censor = FALSE,
           legend = c(0.5, 0.2),
           legend.title = "Mon3, P=0.02",
           legend.labs = c("Quartile 1", "Quartile 2", "Quartile 3", "Quartile 4"),
           xlab = "Follow-up (months)",
           font.x = c(size = 15),
           ylab = "Survival from MACE",
           font.y = c(size = 15),
           break.y.by = 0.2,
           axes.offset = FALSE,
           palette = c("blue", "dark red", "green", "orange"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Allan Cameron. Unfortunately, I don't have the same graph. All my data drop to 0 before 20 months. see the question to see what it looks like.

Comment: @MaxB that doesn't make any sense to me. I have included a code block called FULLY REPRODUCIBLE SCRIPT. If you copy this and run it you should get the result you need. The problem might be that in your own data frame the numbers are actually characters. I have fixed this in the reproducible example.

Comment: Great @Allan Cameron. It works perfectly now. The problem was that I had to convert to Int variables all of the variables except of the ```mace_months_date_vs_date_sample```. Thank you very much for your support and patience.